# PySpark works in CLI but not in VS Code IDE

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have Python 3.10.8, PySpark 3.3.1 and JDK 17 (according to Apache Spark website it is supported). When I run PySpark in CLI it starts SparkSession correctly, however in VS Code in both notebook and CLI I get an error "Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number" and more precisely:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:54)
at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:1095)
at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1022)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make private java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @4bde3f8a
```

In VS Code PySpark is just unable to build a SparkSession, despite the same Python/JDK/PySpark version. I was trying to figure it out on my own for a few hours, but I cannot get to the root of the issue. I would be thankful for any suggestions what can be the source of the problem here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue has been solved once I have run PySpark with JDK 11, namely I changed the JAVA_HOME variable in .zshrc so that it referred to location of JDK 11 instead of JDK 17. Now PySpark works perfectly well both in the VS Code and CLI. For anyone who might have this issue and bump into this answer; make sure your JAVA_HOME path is set correctly to JDK 11 (you can download it from Oracle website or using homebrew) in the .zshrc file. After you set it, make sure you restart both CLI and IDE. It should solve the issue. :)